# How to use array_map with reset callback in php 8

Tags: php, foreach, reset, array-map, php-8

I have a function that work good in php 7 but in php 8.0.11 has warning

```
$orders->result = array_map('reset', $orders->result);

E_WARNING: reset(): Argument #1 ($array) must be passed by reference, value given in
```

Of course, I can use this code instead that but maybe slower than array_map

```
foreach ($orders->result as $item)
       $result[$item[0]['order_id']] = $item[0];
```

**Edit:**
before `foreach` or `array_map` the output like this

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [order_id] => 41111909
           [shop_id] => 34277
           [user_id] => 42363
           [status_id] => 4
         )
)
```

after use `foreach` output like this

```
Array
(
    [41111909] => Array
        (
           [order_id] => 41111909
           [shop_id] => 34277
           [user_id] => 42363
           [status_id] => 4
         )
)
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65947307/argument-1-parser-must-be-passed-by-reference
maybe that will help

Comment: *"Of course, I can use this code instead that but maybe slower than array_map"* I think this is false.

Comment: Your alternative code doesn't seem to actually do the same thing - it looks up 'order_id' on each item. It would be equivalent to `array_map(fn($item) => $item[0]['order_id'], $orders->result)`. I also agree with AymDev that it's not particularly likely to be slow.

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: Your latest edit is **even more** confusing: it's not the result that **either** of the versions of the code you showed would give. I would strongly recommend stepping back and creating a [mre] - some actual example input and code that you can run on its own.

Comment: Yes the first line and the other code and arrays don't add up, but edited in a solution for the wanted array.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest replacement is to make an [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) (single-expression closure) to get the element for you.

If the arrays are plain lists, so that you're always getting element `0`, that's as simple as:

```
$orders->result = array_map(fn($item) => $item[0], $orders->result);
```

Another alternative in this case is [array_column](https://www.php.net/array_column):

```
$orders->result = array_colum($orders->result, 0);
```

If you have other keys, you could use either `reset` or `array_key_first` in the callback instead:

```
$orders->result = array_map(fn($item) => $item[array_key_first($item)], $orders->result);
```

(I suspect array_key_first will be slightly more efficient, since it doesn't need to manipulate the internal array pointer.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but it seems like you are trying to get the first value from nested arrays.  You should be able to use a function:

```
$orders->result = array_map(function($v) { return reset($v); }, $orders->result);
```

You may also try using `current` if it does what you need as it doesn't take a reference and the array pointer should already be reset by `array_map`:

```
$orders->result = array_map('current', $orders->result);
```

After the edit the code in question is not re-indexing the array as you show in the before and after.  To do that is simple:

```
$orders->result = array_column($orders->result, null, 'order_id');
```